# Inequalities with entropy with bracketing

Tags: statistics

Show that for all $1\leq p < \infty$:

$$H_p(\delta, \mathcal G, Q) \leq H_{p, B}(\delta, \mathcal G, Q) \leq H_\infty (\delta / 2, \mathcal G)$$

where $H_p$ is the $\delta$-entropy of the class of functions $\mathcal G$ under the $L_p(Q)$ norm and $H_{p, B}$ is the entropy with bracketing and $H_\infty$ is the $\delta$ entropy under the sup norm.

**What I've tried**

For the first inequality we can show that a set of brackets of size $\delta$ for $\mathcal G$ yields a $\delta$ covering of $\mathcal G$. Notice that for a function $g \in \mathcal G$ and it's bracket $[g_j^L, g_j^U]$ we have:

$$\|g_j^L - g\|_{p, Q} + \|g_j^U - g\|_{p, Q}= \|g_j^L - g_j^U\|_{p, Q} \leq \delta$$

So either the $g_j^L$ or $g_j^U$ suffice as a covering set.

For the second inequality I'm having more trouble. My original thought was to try the same method as for the first inequality or try to construct a bracket from a sup norm $\delta$ covering but I have not found a way to do that in a way that implies the inequality. I've also tried rephrasing the requirement as:

If $H_\infty(\delta/2, \mathcal G) \leq N$ then $H_{p, B}(\delta, \mathcal G, Q) \leq N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a sup-norm covering of radius $\delta/2$, call it $\{g_j\}$, consider the brackets $[g_j^L, g_j^U]$ where $g_j^L(x) = g_j(x) - \delta/2$ and $g_j^U(x) = g_j (x) + \delta/2$. If $Q$ is a probability measure, then $\|g^L_j - g^U_j\|_{p, Q} = \delta$, and by construction these brackets cover $\mathcal{G}$.